# Bootstrap modal appearing under background while using jade

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pug

I'm a starting on node.js and jade, I got an app in google app engine working with twitter bootstrap.

**Problem** When I converted the same html to jade though, the modal isn't behaving as it should, rather the background comes over it. I removed fade class but to no avail. Here's the code in jade

```
  #newWordModal.modal.hide
    .modal-header
      button.close(type='button', data-dismiss='modal') x
      h3 Add A Word
    .modal-body
      #create-word
        input#new-word-name(type='text', placeholder='Type in a word name')
        input#new-word-def(type='text', placeholder='Define it....')
    .modal-footer
      a.btn(href='#', data-dismiss='modal') Close
      a#add-word.btn.btn-primary(href='#', data-dismiss='modal') Add Word!
```

The same in html is this

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="newWordModal">
  <div class="modal-header">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
   <h3>Add A Word</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div id="create-word">
    <input type="text" id="new-word-name" placeholder="Type in a word name" />
    <input type="text" id="new-word-def" placeholder="Define it...." />
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
   <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="add-word">Add Word!</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Have I missed something here?

Comment: Do you import correctly the bootstrap js file ?

Answer (score 0):

i think you are missing the 'modal.dialog' and 'modal-content' class as the  content wrapper, as described [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

your code then should look like this

```
#playlistloadmodal.modal.fade
        .modal-dialog
            .modal-content
                .modal-header
                    button.close(type='button', data-dismiss='modal') x
                .modal-body
                    #create-word
                        input#new-word-name(type='text', placeholder='Type in a word name')
                        input#new-word-def(type='text', placeholder='Define it....')
                .modal-footer
                    a.btn(href='#', data-dismiss='modal') Close
                    a#add-word.btn.btn-primary(href='#', data-dismiss='modal') Add Word!
```